# How should we tag allergy-related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two kinds of allergy-related questions: *human* allergies *to* pets, and *pets'* allergies.  I asked a question about the former and tagged it [allergies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergies), but that doesn't leave room for separately tagging questions about the latter.  (I have a cat with allergies and I anticipate asking questions related to that.  **Update:** I've now asked a question about feline allergies too, using the same tag.)

Should we separate these cases?  If so, what should the tags be called?

Comment: Nice question, we definitely require two different tag for it but what to name them....i am also confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do we need different tags, since they all deal with allergies? A person or a pet can have allergies, caused by something else (be it the pet, some food, etc.).

Sometimes, someone will research using tags "cat" and "allergies", and will discover that it's about a person who has problems with cats. Ok, just close the page, open the next result, and move on. It's not worth the effort of having two separate tags... and even if we had them, no one will read all the tag list before asking the question. He'll only know that there was a specific tag after searching, finding it, reading, and then realizing he could have asked differently.

Comment: I concur.  The other tags on the questions should cover most cases, and the other cases should be covered by reading the question or the title alone

Answer (score 1):

If someone is searching for pet specific allergies or human specific allergies, there should hopefully be enough in the question title to indicate whether we are dealing with pets or humans, which allows for there only needing to be one allergies tag instead of multiple.

We might want to avoid a lot of very specific tags as it makes it difficult for new users to know which tags to use (possibly) and it also makes it harder to group things together.

In this case, it is not all that specific, but at the same time, tags are not the only way to search or sort information, so it is likely that the question title can take over some of the job of making a more specific determination between just whose allergies we are talking about.